# Use parallel to split many directories into subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, gnu, gnu-parallel

I want to use `parallel` to split many directories into subdirectories. E.g. I have 1 000 000 directories with content, but it's too much for one directory, so I want to create 10 dirs in the main dir and move in each of them 100 000 original dirs.

I already tried `ls -tr|parallel -n100000 mkdir "dir_{#}"\;mv {} "dir_{#}"` command, but it moves only ~10 000 into one subdir(sometimes ~6200, sometimes ~12 500) and create too much subdirs - sometimes in 10 times more than I need.
Of course, I don't need exactly 100 000 dirs in each subdir, it can be 101 000 or 98 500 dirs, it should be a number in the range of 100 000

So, how can I do this using `parallel`?

Comment: should we assume that `ls -tr` list only directories in your case? cause it also lists files

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, because I have only dirs in this dir, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

GNU **`parallel`** solution:

```
parallel -j10 -n100000 --no-notice -k 'mkdir -p dir_{#}; mv {} -t dir_{#}' ::: *
```

---

- `j N` - number of jobslots. Run up to `N` jobs in parallel. In your case we'll run 10 jobs to distribute(move) all directories between new 10 parent directories
- `-n100000` - use at most `100000` arguments (dirnames) per command line
- `{#}` - sequence number of the job to run. This replacement string will be replaced by the sequence number of the job being run
- `::: arguments` - use `arguments` from the command line as input source instead of stdin (standard input)

---

To process directories(dirnames) sorted by modification time - use the following pipeline:

```
ls -dtr * | parallel -j10 -n100000 --no-notice -k 'mkdir -p dir_{#}; mv {} -t dir_{#}'
```

Comment: Many thanks! And how can I use sort flags for sorting by date, as in the my original command?

Comment: @don-prog, welcome, see my additional approach

Comment: Unfortunately now I get `bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long` output, how can I make it work?

Comment: @don-prog, that, unfortunately could happen. This situation was mentioned if officia manual https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Inserting-multiple-arguments. The nuance is that you have decided to distribute too many directory names only between 10 parent directories

Comment: Try to decrease the number of arguments per job (let's say `-n10000`)

Comment: I tried to reduce the parameter to `-n10`, but even now I have this error

Comment: I also tried this command: `ls -tr | parallel -j10 -n100000 --no-notice -k 'mkdir -p dir_{#}; mv {} -t dir_{#}'` (without `d` and `*`) and it works, but with **exactly same result** as I had for command in the my original question. So, I'm completely confused. Any ideas?