# Use parallel to split many directories into subdirectories or parallelize this task

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, gnu, gnu-parallel

I want to parallelize spliting of many directories into subdirectories using `parallel` or using another tool or method.

E.g. I have 1 000 000 directories with content, but it's too much for one directory, so I want to create 10 dirs in the main dir and move in each of them 100 000 original dirs. I also want to use sorting by date. I already asked [similar question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406408/use-parallel-to-split-many-directories-into-subdirectories), but this isn't duplicate, because I tried new commands, got new results and now I reformulated the question.

So, I already tried this

```
ls -tr|parallel -n100000 mkdir "dir_{#}"\;mv {} "dir_{#}"
```

and this

```
ls -tr | parallel -j10 -n100000 --no-notice -k 'mkdir -p dir_{#}; mv {} -t dir_{#}'
```

commands, but it moves only ~10 000 into one subdir(sometimes ~6200, sometimes ~12 500) and create too much subdirs - sometimes in 10 times more than I need.

I also tried to use this:

```
ls -dtr * | parallel -j10 -n100000 --no-notice -k 'mkdir -p dir_{#}; mv {} -t dir_{#}'
```

but it gave `bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long`.

Of course, I don't need exactly 100 000 dirs in each subdir, it can be 101 000 or 98 500 dirs, it should be a number in the range of 100 000

How can I execute this task in parallel or using `parallel`?

Comment: I/O actions don't parallelize well; everyone needs access to the disk, but the disk can only do so much at once.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams as I wrote, I already parallelized it(or just accelerated), the only problem is that I get the wrong number of dirs and subdirs.

Comment: Regarding parallelization and I/O: Try sorting by inode: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124527/speed-up-copying-1000000-small-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem deals with heavy IO. I doubt that `parallel` is really useful in this situation.

Anyway I suggest that you consider a "traditional" approach:

```
 mkdir dir_{1..10}
 ls -tr | nl | \
    awk '$2 !~ /^dir_/ {i=1+int($1/100000); print $2 | "xargs mv -t dir_"i}'
```

where

- `ls -tr | nl`  sorts the directories by date and adds an auxiliar dir-number
- `$2 !~ /^dir_/` is used to skip the just-created folders.
- `i=1+int($1/100000)` calculates the number of the folder based on the dir-number
- `print $2 | "xargs mv -t dir_"i` moves without process proliferation

If possible compare also the respective times: `time ....` (and share the results with us ☺)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `time` results: your command - 1.24 minutes, etopylight's command - 2.45 minutes for 300 000 dirs.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that print can be piped to an external command inside awk :)

Comment: @etopylight, thank you! Awk has some very cool details. The main reason why why awk is fast is that disk mechanical elements end up making it "serial". Your solution (that I up-voted) is very useful for the (and faster) for the not-so-IO-intensitive situations.

Comment: @don-prog, thank you the comment and for the time results.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there is an upper limit of bytes that a command line can take after shell expansion, this limit depends on the system's limit

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

thus causing the number of argument by `mv {}` to vary depending on the input filename's length whenever you hit the max limit.

A solution to avoid this limit while not giving up using parallel is to split the task into two stages

```
ls -tr | parallel -N 100000 --pipe -k "mkdir dir_{#}; parallel -X mv -t dir_{#}"
```

**Explaination**

- The first stage uses the option `--pipe` to split the stdin into a determined number of **smaller stdins**, each containing n lines as specified by the option `-N`. You can observe the effect by using this example

  ```
  seq 1000000 | parallel -N 100000 --pipe wc -l
  ```

  which gives an exact split at the 100000 mark

  ```
  100000
  100000
  100000
  ...
  ```
- On the second stage, the inner parallels take the **smaller stdins** as their new stdin to execute their jobs, the `-X` option inserts as many arguments as the command line length permits

  ```
  mkdir dir_{#}; parallel -X mv -t dir_{#}
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `time` results: JJoao's command - 1.24 minutes, your command - 2.45 minutes for 300 000 dirs.